# How should I phrase this complaint about humiliating behavior of officers?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The scenario is: A technician is regular, punctual and honest in his duties, but he usually face humiliating behavior of seniors. His job's nature is that he remains in home until he is called by his officers to do for what he is appointed. He wants to inform his CEO about humiliating behavior of officers.

Following expressions reach my mind in this situation:

> Even after removing all complaints, I face humiliating behavior of my seniors and officers.

or

> Even after satisfying all complaints, which I receive, I have to tolerate humiliating behavior of my seniors and officers.

Which one is right or better?

Comment: Hello, usman ali. Sorry for the victim here. Also sorry that this sort of question is off-topic. I can't put 'I have to tolerate humiliation from my seniors and officers. This in spite of the fact that I try to address any genuine complaints I receive.' in an answer.

Comment: Here are some words you could use:  'Even though I am fulfilling my tasks to the best of my abilities, and responding to the requests of my seniors, they are treating me in a humiliating way that I feel is unjustified and that I can't tolerate'. Good luck! Something like this happened to me too, and when I reported it to the personnel department, they listened, and the bully was kicked out. I still have the white streak in my hair from that experience though... I should have sued them for that... 

Comment: It should be "I face humiliation from ..."

Comment: You were humiliated BY them.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

> My superiors humiliate me even after I've successfully resolved every complaint or issue they've given me.

Comment: The original talked about "satisfying all complaints" which is different from "not making mistakes".  I would suggest, "Even after correcting my mistakes, however minor, I am still repeatedly shamed and humiliated by my superiors."

Comment: Answer doesn't seem relevant to question. Recommended action is add information regarding the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, humiliate is not the best verb for this context. You could say that your supervisors

**belittle/demean/criticize/micromanage**

you. But saying they “humiliate” would be more appropriate for a personal context, like friends who are pranking you. In a professional setting, it comes off as unnecessarily inflammatory.

Answer (score -1):

A fine colloquial term is constructed as "they treat me like a [X]" where X is a locally despised minority, servant, pack animal, or other such imposed-upon creatures. It suggests they are domineering and disrespectful of any rights you imagine to have. Eg "they treat me like a whipping boy".